# How to catch or mock unexpected exceptions in mockito+J-unit test's?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

This is the function in the main file for where i need to write test for.

```
@Override
public void processTask(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws TaskException {

    if (BatchInputChannel.DB.toString().equals(runtimeContext.getProperties().getProperty(BATCH_CHANNEL_TYPE))) {
        return;
    } else if (BatchInputChannel.FILE.toString().equals(runtimeContext.getProperties().getProperty(BATCH_CHANNEL_TYPE))) {
        jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) beanFactory.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) beanFactory.getBean("micorpFileLoadJob");
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                                                .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                                .toJobParameters();
        try {
            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
            System.out.println("jobExecution=="+jobExecution);
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            throw new ProcessingException("File Loading Failed" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And this i the test function which i tried to create

```
@Test(expected = JobParametersInvalidException.class)
public void processTaskWithFileInputJobFailed5() throws Exception {
    when(mockruntimeContext.getProperties()).thenReturn(mockProperties);
    when(mockProperties.getProperty(BATCH_CHANNEL_TYPE)).thenReturn("FILE");

    when(mockbeanFactory.getBean("jobLauncher")).thenReturn(mockJobLauncher);
    when(mockbeanFactory.getBean("micorpFileLoadJob")).thenReturn(mockjob);

    mockjobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
    when(mockJobLauncher.run(mockjob, mockjobParameters)).thenReturn(mockJobExecution);
    when(mockJobExecution.getStatus()).thenReturn(BatchStatus.FAILED);
    when(mockJobExecution.getJobConfigurationName()).thenReturn(null);
    Mockito.doThrow(new JobParametersInvalidException("Invalid")).when(mockJobLauncher).run(mockjob, mockjobParameters);
    inputFileLoaderTaskProcessor.processTask(mockjobExecutionContext);
}
```

When i am executing the project as a J-unit test,its expecting processing exception to be thrown,but i have mentioned "JobParametersInvalidException" in expected.

As you can see I have only added one exception in this function,in order to cover all the exceptions(inside catch) in the main function what needs to be done?

Comment: But the JobParametersInvalidException is an internal implementation detail f the processTask;  that method never exits with it, so it should never be expected. 
 Instead, have `@Test(expected = ProcessingException.class)`

Comment: @racraman but after running the test its's showing the catch as it is not covered.I was trying for 100 % coverage

Comment: @racraman also i have created  function to cover the processing exception.That function is passed when i executed it as  J-unit test.

Comment: Would you please provide the declaration of the private fields used in your tests? The mocked ones (possible @Mock annotated) and the class being tested (which I supposed was annotated with @InjectMocks). And also, please, the annotations used in the tested class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mockito.doThrow(new JobParametersInvalidException("Invalid")).when(mockJobLauncher).run(mockjob, mockjobParameters);
```

This doThrow is not being invoked because the parameters will not match.

In the code, the parameters is set by :

```
   JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                            .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                                            .toJobParameters();
```

In the unit test, the matching mock is set by :

```
mockjobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
```

The trouble is, the millisecond clock would almost certainly have ticked over between when the test was being set up, and when the code under test executes.  That means these parameters will not be equal, and so the exception is not being thrown.

Change the mock setup to expect any JobParameters, eg something like :

```
Mockito.doThrow(new JobParametersInvalidException("Invalid")).when(mockJobLauncher).run(eq(mockjob), any(JobParameters.class));
```

Comment: when i change the code this is the error that i am getting

Comment: Invalid use of argument matchers,2 matchers expected recorded 1

Comment: you do have the "eq" on the first one?

Comment: eq(mockJob)  was showing error .So changed it to just mockJob.Can i change it to any(Job.class)?

Comment: Don't know why that should be, but certainly try that change.  That error message you were getting is because Mockito insists either NONE of the arguments have matchers, or they ALL do - ie, as soon as one has a matcher, then they all must do.

Comment: I forgot to import eq after that some slight adjustments here and there and it worked like like a treat.Thanks.